# php form processing POST

Tags: php, post

I'm trying to use form processing to make a specific database query. I set the form to $name and am trying to process $sql = "SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE qSymbol = $name ORDER BY qQuoteDateTime DESC"
What is the best way to do this?

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
<span></span><input type = "text" value=" " name="boxy" />
<br/><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter" />
</form>

<?php
    $name = $_POST['boxy'];
    if(isset($_POST['boxy'])){
        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

        $con = mysql_connect('...');
        if (!$con){
            die("Cannot connect : " . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db('quotesdb',$con);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE qSymbol = '$name' ORDER BY qQuoteDateTime DESC";
        $myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
        echo "<table border = 1>
        <tr>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Last</th>
        <th>Change</th>
        <th>% Chg</th>
        <th>Volume</th>
        </tr>";

        while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $record['qQuoteDateTime'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $record['qLastSalePrice'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $record['qNetChangePrice'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $record['qNetChangePct'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $record['qShareVolumeQty'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

        echo "</table>";



        mysql_close($con);




        }
```

Comment: Please don't use the deprecated and unsafe `mysql` functions. Switch to using either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

You will still need single quotes around the variable unless it's a number

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE qSymbol = '$name' ORDER BY qQuoteDateTime DESC";
```

Comment: Thanks. It still does not seem to be working. Nothing happens after I press enter, but I can see the variable is changing.

Comment: I assumed you omitted the code. You still need to execute the query and fetch results

Comment: I did. I edited the original question to include all of my code. I'm assuming it's something in the form, it works when I set $name = 'something'

Comment: Try deleting `value=" " `